# Google Analytics realtime shows mismatched data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

which one of the following is correct in the Google Analytics dashboard?

[image]

The "Right Now" or the "Metric Total"? how many users I actually have??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug of Google Analytics real time report.

It has been observed that the inflated number of active users, after a more or less expanded period of time, returns to normal, and then eventually resumes the anomalous count and subsequently re-enters the ranks again.

What probably happens is an accumulation of the number of active users over time without, however, the total being decreased once the user is no longer in that state.

https://www.analyticstraps.com/bug-numero-anomalo-di-utenti-attivi-in-tempo-reale/